# How can I read the value of dictionary Inside list which is Inside a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The format is this way :

```
dict = {key : {key1 : val1, key2 : val2, key3 : [{k1 : v1, k2 : v2, k3:v3}],key4 : val4}}
```

so If I want to read *k2*, then how can I do this? actually I was using :

dict[key][key3][0][k2] but this is not working. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are the keys in the `dict = {...}` in ' ' or " "? If they are, maybe it has something to do with dict being a reserved name

Comment: It is in double quote " "

Comment: `dict` is a built-in type name, but it isn't a reserved keyword, so it's possible to overwrite it. I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: When I run this code I get `NameError: name 'key' is not defined`. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If all the keys really are in quotes, then that method of access [works fine on my machine](https://ideone.com/w1OGvP). There's probably something wrong with your real code that didn't translate over when you anonymized the details for this question.

Answer (score 2):

To read the value stored in `k2`:

```
dict = {key : {key1 : val1, key2 : val2, key3 : [{k1 : v1, k2 : v2, k3:v3}],key4 : val4}}
k2_val = dict[key][key3][0][k2]
```